# How do you create volume for a disk on diskpart for windows 10 so you can format the disk to fat32?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, formatting, diskpart

After cleaning Disk 2, I made a partition with [diskpart](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskpart) to Disk 2 after cleaning it,

I've tried to create a volume for that disk but none of my code attempts have worked for example, "create simple volume size=20000 disk=2 partition=1". I also need to convert the disk to dynamic so i can format the volume to fat32. It says, "The command you selected is not available with this version of Windows."

Comment: you have it backwards, it should be `create volume simple size=20000 disk=2 ` and the `partition=1` flag is not a valid syntax and should be removed. Ref: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/create-volume-simple

Comment: I used the following code and now It's saying i need a dynamic disk. How do you convert a disk to dynamic?

Comment: `diskpart` then `select disk 2` then `convert dynamic`

Comment: I used this exact command and it says "the command you selected is not available with this version of Windows"

Comment: Why do you create volume instead of partition (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/create-partition-primary)? What does dynamic disk have to do with FAT32? You may also want to try/do `convert mbr` beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

*Dynamic* disk partitioning is passe, and not very long lived. Back up any data and/or media on that drive, copying local files to a separate place, then verify the backup was good.

Once the backup is verified, reformat the drive as a [Basic disk](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/basic-and-dynamic-disks), then reinstall Windows